# finitely generated ideal and number of generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

let $I$ be a finitely generated ideal of ring $R$.

Suppose $I/I^2$ as an $R/I$ module is generated by $r$ elements then question is to prove that $I$ is generated by $r+1$ elements..

I have tried induction on number of generators of $I$ but could not succeed..

I have then tried to prove for $r=0$..

Suppose $r=0$ i.e., $I/I^2=0$ i.e, $I=I^2$..

Now, $I$ is finitely generated ideal and we have $IM=M$ for $M=I$..

Then by nakayama lemma, we see that there exists $a\in I$ such that $(1+a)M=0$

Let $m\in I$ then $(1+a)m=0$ i.e., $m=-am$..

Thus, $I\subseteq (-a)$.. Other inclusion is trivial. so, we have $I=(-a)$ generated by $1$ element...

I am thinking of using same idea for $r\neq 0$..

Suppose $r=1$ then we have $I/I^2=\langle a+I^2\rangle$ i.e., $I=\langle a \rangle +I^2$.. Now,I want to write $I=\langle a \rangle +I^2=JI$ for some 
ideal $J$ and repeat the same as in the case of $r=0$. But could not think of any such $J$.. Please help me to solve this...

Please do not write answers, give some hints..

Comment: Here is something stronger and useful. With your hypothesis, let $f\in R$ be any element. Then the ideal generated by $I$ and $f$ is generated by $r+1$ elements. Taking $f=0$, you prove what you want, but $f$ can be arbitrary!

Comment: @Mohan, this is indeed a very nice result to remember, I would like to see the argument if you have time.

Comment: @user114539 Using the notation in my answer below, $i'$ is generated by the image of a single element $a\in I$ and as pointed out in the question above, we may assume $a$ is idempotent in $I'$. Then $I+fR$ is generated by $J$ and $a+(1-a)f$.

Answer (score 3):

If $I/I^2$ is generated by $r$ elements, you can pick $r$ elements in $I$ which generates $I/I^2$. Let $J$ be the ideal generated by these $r$ elements and then consider $S=R/J$ and $I'=I/J$ an ideal in $S$. Then $I'/I'^2=0$ and you have your argument for this case, showing $I'$ is generated by one element and thus $I$ is generated by $r+1$ elements. My statement, which is stronger can also proved fairly easily and I can write it if you wish.

Comment: I think i got it.. for $r=1$ we have $I=\langle a\rangle +I^2$.. Consider $J=\langle a\rangle$... Let $m\in I$ then, $m\in \langle a\rangle +pq$ for some $p,q\in I$ i.e., $m-pq\in  \langle a\rangle$ i.e., $m+ \langle a\rangle=(p+ \langle a\rangle)(q+ \langle a\rangle)$ i.e., $I/J=(I/J)^2$... Now, as $I$ is finitely generated then so is $I/J$... then by same argument as that in my question i would get $m\in I/J$ such that $I/J=\langle m+J\rangle$ then, $I= \langle a\rangle+ \langle m\rangle$.. This is the case for any $r$..

Comment: So, as of now, i understand how does this work... I will be glad if you can give some motivation how did you come up with this idea.....

Comment: I mean to say $I= \langle a,m\rangle$